# Is the "gluing" of continuous maps continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces, $X=X_1\cup X_2$, where $X_1$, $X_2$ are closed and carry subspace topology induced from $X$. Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a map such that $f|_{X_1}:X_1\rightarrow Y$, $f|_{X_2}:X_2\rightarrow Y$ are continuous. Is it true that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes. Just take the $f$-preimage of a closed subset in $Y$ and consider the intersections of the preimage with the $X_i$'s. I afraid of that this is a wrong place to ask such questions.

Comment: There was no typo--amazing!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the answer is given by the "pasting lemma", see the proof here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma